# cmake compile main program as c and unit tests as c++

Tags: cmake

I am using catch for unit test framework which requires my c files to be compiled as c++. However, when running the main program, I want it to be compiled as C.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(maintenance)

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c maintenance.c)
add_executable(maintenance ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(MY_TEST_SOURCES maintenance.c maintenance_test.cpp)
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES( maintenance.c PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX )
add_executable(maintenance_test ${MY_TEST_SOURCES})
```

Using the SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES I can force the specific file to be compiled as C++ but then I am unable to compile the main program. Commenting the line out, then I can compile the main program but not the unit tests.

How can I make cmake to compile the main program as c and the test sources as c++?

Comment: From my point of view, having original program to be "C" but testing it as "C++" has a little sence. If you expect exception to be thrown by the testing system, it is sufficient to compile `maintenance.c` as "C". If program itself may throw exception (directly or via calling "C++" function), then `maintenance.c` should be compiled as "C++" even for production.

Comment: The test framework "catch" requires the c file to be compiled as c++. The code in my specific case, needs to be compiled in c.

Comment: @George: Nothing requires a C file to be compiled as C++ actually.  Maybe you can explain a bit more what exactly goes wrong if you compile your code as C?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to make a symlink:

```
ln -s maintenance.c maintenance-test.cpp
```

Then you can compile two objects: one using your C compiler and one using C++.

You can even have CMake create the symlink as part of the generation step:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT maintenance-test.cpp
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink maintenance.c maintenance-test.cpp)
```